# Git with Visual Studio does strange things with my .csproj

Tags: asp.net, git, visual-studio

Ok, this is a weird one and I have no clue how to get arround this problem. I'm using the following setup:

- Visual Studio 2017 v15.6.7
- Git v2.17.0.windows.1

I been working with this for a while and for the first time something strange happens when I add or remove an image from a web project content/images directory.

Here are steps to reproduce this behavior in my project. Don't know if this also happens with other projects.

1. We use 'development' as our development branche
2. Create a new branche from 'development' named 'wake_on_lan'
3. Check the branche has switched to 'wake_on_lan'

> C:\Projects\P2G\P2G>git status
>       On branch wake_on_lan
>       nothing to commit, working tree clean

4. Navigate to the Content/Images directory
5. Click the wakeonlan.png and right click it and select 'Exclude from project'

[image]

> git status On branch wake_on_lan Your branch is up to date with
>   'origin/wake_on_lan'.
>
> Changes not staged for commit:   (use "git add ..." to update
>   what will be committed)   (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard
>   changes in working directory)
>
> ```
>     modified:   Sources/WUR.P2G.WEB/Wur.P2G.Web.csproj
>     modified:   Sources/Wur.P2G.Web/Wur.P2G.Web.csproj
> ```
>
> no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

6. Goto the Team Explorer. The change in .csproj is now visible.

[image]

7. Commit the change and here it becomes weird. The change is committed but another change becomes visible to the same file (.csproj).

Git status tells the .csproj is modified (in red) but no changes are staged.
Can't undo the change with VS.
Can't checkout -- .csproj with git command line
Gitkraken says there's a conflict but cant discard changes either

[image]

After this the only way I found so far to restore at least the project is to make a new clone from the repo.

I read somewhere I had to add *.csproj merge = union to the .gitattributes file but that makes no difference.

Comment: 1. make sure you press "save all" before step 6, 2. please provide output of git status at each step, 3 check `git diff` output after steps 6 and 7

Comment: Hey good point. Look there are 2 modifications for the .csproj. The one has uppercase directory name where the other has CamelCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have the file duplicated in the repository with different cases. You can verify it by command `git ls-tree -r HEAD`.

You should remove one of them. Easiest way to do it is to use a Linux computer or some web interface. It should be possible at Windows somehow, but I cannot say how without trying it.

Comment: Yep, that's it. I didn't know Git is case sensitive. VS does not take that into account and that caused the duplication.

Comment: B.t.w. the git ls-tree-r HEAD command is not available in Git for Windows. I was able to delete the duplicate using the web interface.

Comment: Apparently I mistyped it, there should have been a space. Edited now right.

Comment: It tries to be case-insensitive at Windows, but in its core it is case sensitive, so it can contain clashing names. Though it would be interesting to find out how did they appear it you only used it at Windows.

Comment: My guess is that Visual Studio messed up. I tried to rename the project from ALL UPPERCASE to CamelCase. That probably caused this to happen.